# command line code from C# doesn't run in the right order?

Tags: c#, command-line

I have the following code:

```
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = args[1];
            string output = args[3];

            Console.WriteLine("Finished parsing input");

            // runs an executable file called myexe.exe
            // this exe creates an output file with the hardcoded name exeoutput.txt
            string runexe = string.Format("/C myexe.exe -i {0}", input);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", runexe);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished running exe");

            // moves the output created by myexe.exe to a new location
            string moveOutput = string.Format("/C move exeoutput.txt {0}", output);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", moveOutput);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished moving output");
        }
    }
}
```

I run this code with the command `MyProject.exe -i input.txt -o output.txt`.

The first time I run the command I get this output:

```
Finished parsing input
Finished running exe
Finished moving output
C:\Users\me\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debu\netcoreapp3.1>The system cannot find the file specified
[some output from myexe.exe]
```

The second time I run it I get this output:

```
Finished parsing input
Finished running exe
Finished moving output
C:\Users\me\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debu\netcoreapp3.1> 1 file(s) moved.
[some output from myexe.exe]
```

It seems like the C# code is first executing the print statements, second executing the move file command, and then third executing `myexe.exe`. Why is this happening and how can I enforce the order?

Comment: Are you expecting the C# process to wait for the started process to finish?  You need extra code for that.

Comment: I think that after running the first CMD.EXE you should wait the termination and not start another CMD.EXE There is a Process.WaitForExit()

Comment: This line `string runexe = string.Format("/C myexe.exe -i {0}, input);` will not compile

Comment: Probably a Typo.

Comment: fixed the typo, but that wasn't the cause of my issue

Comment: `Process.Start` starts the process, but does not wait for it to finish. You need to keep a reference to the started process and then call `thatProcessVariable.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: how do I keep a reference to the started process? I've found ways to do it for just cmd.exe, but I can't figure out how to do it while running `/C myexe.exe -i input.txt` through it

Comment: I keep wondering why none looks at the docs before coming here to ask questions. There are thousands of examples on how to start a process and keep a reference to the started process so you can WaitForExit. Please [start reading from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with processes, and wasn't sure if I still needed to start `cmd.exe` as my process, or if i could go directly with `myexe.exe`. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Dispose  process object like this

```
  using (Process myProcess = new Process())
                {
                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.Start();
                    // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
                    // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
                    // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
                    // from this application using the Kill method.
                }
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to wait, see also [Process.WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: [Copycat the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8)?